# What non-research activities are most valuable when applying for faculty positions in mathematics?

Tags: career-path, teaching, mathematics, faculty-application, service-activities

I am asking this question for two reasons: first to work on activities to strengthen my CV for the future, and second to write a plan for professional development activities as part of a grant proposal.

What non-research related activities are most valuable to have on a CV when applying to permanent faculty positions at research-focused universities? For example, how valuable is it to have experience working with graduate students, organizing conferences/seminars, etc.?

I am a pure mathematician, hoping for advice that can apply to both European and American jobs. I currently am working on my second postdoc, although my first one was only six months long.  I had to take some adjunct teaching positions here and there as well, so I have a decent amount of undergraduate teaching experience. I have a limited publication record however (one thing I *know* I need to work on).

Answer (score 6):

What is valued around here is to show independent work (not just papers with your advisor, have your own research grants). Show involvement with the relevant community (organize conferences, attend conferences, get invited to talk about your work).

Answer (score 3):

I decided to focus on the following:

1. More (high quality) publications
2. Assist in supervising students
3. Participate in organizing conferences
4. Build on my programming/computational skills
5. Focus on international collaborations

I figure this mostly covers all of my bases.

Answer (score 3):

Research production is BY FAR the most important for R1 universities.  They figure you can figure out the teaching.  But they don't think a teacher is going to figure out how to be Einstein.  And (despite, I would argue it is a fallacy for the interests of undergrads who actually want to learn, not do research), having Einsteins is helpful to premier school.

If you can show some evidence of moving to a PI status (e.g. getting a grant, leading a conference session, etc.) that might be a positive.